# Why do some older writings have misused possessives?

Tags: grammaticality, possessives, apostrophe

I was recently visiting the Henry Ford museum, when I came across this old billboard:
[image: "dealer's"]

In case it is difficult to read in the picture, the full text was "See it at your Ford dealer's now!"

Note that dealers is written as "dealer's." Is there anybody who knows why this is? Is it considered proper English, or was it simply an error on the designer's part?

Comment: See it at the shop of your Ford dealer.  No error.

Comment: Better not to worry so much about misused punctuation in other people's writing. It simply causes anxiety without improving anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an omitted, implied word after dealer's.  Like the comment says, it may as well be "shop"

> See it at your Ford dealer's shop.

A more common example of this omission, in my experience, is when talking about going to someone's house:

> There's a party this weekend at Jeff's.

The implication, of course, is that we're going to Jeff's house.

Comment: Alright, thanks. It just seemed odd with the word "now" after it.